# Automating a JNLP Application using Java Agents

Tags: java, applet, jnlp

I'm trying to automate some operations in a jnlp application using a Java Agent that gets into the "VM instance of the app" and then create a new instance of my Swing GUI(and my class for automation).

It works fine, I can access the components of the Frames. The problem is that my GUI runs as an "applet" which gives me a yellow annoying triangle at the corner of my GUI and also cut off my permissions(like file accessing).

The JNLP has the `<application-desc main-class="x"/>` setting in the JNLP file so the app doesn't run as an applet.

How can I run my Swing GUI as an application and not an applet?

Code of the JavaAgent

```
public class FrameSearcherAgent {

   public static void agentmain(String args) {   

   Frame[] frames = Frame.getFrames();        
   for(Frame f: frames)
   {          
      if(f.getTitle().equals("Frame Title")){
         //Parameter is the Frame I want
         new JFrameAutomateGUI(f).setVisible(true);
         break;
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that my GUI runs as an "applet" which gives me a yellow annoying triangle at the corner of my GUI..

No, that is wrong.

1. It applies to any applet or JWS app.
2. It is not a problem so much as a safety for the user, and a challenge we must face when deploying apps.

> ..and also cut off my permissions (like file accessing).

It is possible to access the local file-system in any application or applet deployed using Java Web Start, but it requires different (JWS specific) APIs.  Here is a [demo. of using the JNLP file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

On the other hand:

- The triangle will disappear if the code is digitally signed and the JNLP requests `j2ee-application-client-permissions`.
- The app. will be able to do all the things it can do with no security manager (including showing a `JFileChooser`) if it is signed and the JNLP requests `all-permissions`.

Comment: Ok but there is the problem, I don't run my application from a JNLP... The process is: I have two jars; The first is the "injector" which loops through all the VirtualMachines (VirtualMachine.getlist) and attach to the VM (VirtualMachine.attach) of the application that I want to automate and load my agent(VM.loadAgent); The second is my agent which has the code above(in my post) and my GUI class. My agent is now running inside the VM and It launches my GUI by a simple "new JFrame()". So there is no way I can request "all-permissions" in the JNLP because there is not a JNLP.

Comment: You might need to install a custom `SecurityManager`.